# onItemClick listView off by one, and last item clicked causes crash?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

It appears when I set up my onClickListener for my listview, and set the positioning every listview cell seems to be one off, and the last listview cell causes a crash. For example If I had a listview of 5 items, If I clicked first one, the second one details show up, if I click the second one, the third ones show up - The last item causes a crash, and obviously the first item details are never shown up since its off by one...not sure what the issue is here or how I would go about fixing this? Never ran into this issue...

```
private static void updateUI() {
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                context, bookList,
                R.layout.list_view, new String[] { "bookName",
                        "bookDetails", "bookYear" },
                new int[] { R.id.bookName,
                        R.id.bookDetails,
                        R.id.bookYear });
        mBookList.setAdapter(adapter);
        mBookList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {


                    String externalURL = bookList.get(position).get("site_detail_url");

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, BookWebViewActivity.class);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(externalURL));
                    context.startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
```

Comment: use position-1 instead?

Comment: Have you checked what ID does it return on each click? it looks like an outOfBoundException

Comment: That works, why would that work and not just position? Not sure I'm getting the logic behind that, if I'm trying to call the current position clicked and not minus one, is there something wrong with my data then?

Comment: No saqib, I haven't. how would I go about doing that to check? something like Log.i(mTag, id); ?

Comment: Is `list_view.xml` an empty `ListView` or is there something else?

Comment: brother it just not found the list for showing next item on click of last row thats why..

Comment: Hey guys I think it's because I'm adding a header view to my list view as stated by the guy below me, because thats exactly what im doing and he did as well and got the same issue. I'm going to try to fix it using ListView.getItemAtPosition(int position) as he stated below, I believe that should fix it thanks for all your help and hard work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this occur when adding a header view to my `ListView`.  I solved the problem by using the `ListView` to get my items, rather than the adapter.  See `ListView.getItemAtPosition(int position)` : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html.

Comment: Thats actually exactly what I'm doing is adding a header view to my list view, so I think that is why it's not working correctly! Thanks so much I'll try to look into this and fix it (I'm a noob! lol)

Comment: Not sure how I implement this, tried:     mBookList.getItemAtPosition(position).get("site_detail_url");
but think I'm doing this completely wrong lol

Comment: When you use the listview instead of the adapter, you aren't specifying the generic type, so you'll have to cast to your adapter's object type.  So, YourType type = (YourType) listview.getItemAtPosition(position);  type.get("site_detail_url");

Comment: By the looks of it, it looks like your keeping a reference to your objects in your activity - so yeah, you're probably going about it in the wrong way.  The adapter and listview have references to your data, or in your case your "booklist", so let them manage your booklist data internally, and use provided methods to retrieve the data, rather than keeping a reference and accessing it the way you currently are.

Comment: Ok I did it your way, works great - now only issue is if the header view is clicked I get a crash since that's part of the list I'm assuming. Any ideas?

Comment: if(position != 0), or use the addHeaderView() method that contains more arguments in the constructor - > listView.addHeaderView(view, "Data", false);

Comment: Odd, when I wrap all of the code in the onItemClick in the if (position != 0) , still crashes when header is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
String externalURL = bookList.get(position-1).get("site_detail_url");
```

Comment: Yes that works but still isn't answering my question as to why position isn't working without subtracting 1, is my data incorrect or something? Sounds like my index is off by 1 or something

Comment: bookList is an implementation of List, right? The index starts at 0.